# Firebase: escaping characters in redirect

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a project running for over a year in Firebase.
It has a firebase.json with the following redirect:

```
"redirects": [ {
      "source" : "/single-reports/:id*",
      "destination" : "/dashboard/#!/single-reports/:id",
      "type" : 302
    }],
```

However, suddenly some clients started to complain of an error. I went to check and the url is being redirected to

```
/dashboard/%23%21/single-reports/-LMnXAtEzTQQzffY0Bfy
```

I didn't touch anything. What might have happened? How to fix?

Comment: I have a similar issue: I was using signed URLs in my cloud functions, suddenly the signature stopped working because the query params are encoded/re-written by some kind of google-cloud-proxy, really interested to see if we can raise some awareness and get some help?